Principled Conditional Inheritance in Python
I have a class that inherits np.ndarray:
class A(np.ndarray):
  def __new__(cls, foo: np.ndarray):
    # Operate on foo...
    x = np.array([1.]) + foo # (placeholder)

    return x

  def bar(self, x):
    # Other stuff...

I want to add CPU/GPU-agnostic behaviour by detecting whether the input is a np.ndarray or cupy.ndarray, and dynamically inheriting one of the two, like this:
class A:
  def __new__(cls, foo: Union[np.ndarray, cupy.ndarray]):
    xp = cupy.get_array_module(foo) # Returns either `numpy` or `cupy` depending on `foo`

    # Operate on foo...
    x = xp.array([1.]) + foo # (placeholder)

    return xp.__new__(cls, x)

  def bar(self, x):
    # Other stuff...

I think the following might work, but it's very messy:
class BaseA(ABC):
  def bar(self, x):
    # Other stuff...

class ANumpy(BaseA, np.ndarray):
  pass

class ACupy(BaseA, cupy.ndarray):
  pass

class A:
  def __new__(cls, foo: Union[np.ndarray, cupy.ndarray]):
    if isinstance(foo, cupy.ndarray):
      return ACupy(foo)

    return ANumpy(foo)

How do I do it properly/well?

Do you want to either: always inherit from np.ndarray or always inherit from cupy.ndarray depending on which is installed; or inherit from both within the same code?

why is A a class? Just amke it a function.

@MT0 Inherit from cupy.ndarray if foo uses cupy, and inherit from np.ndarray if foo uses numpy

@juanpa.arrivillaga A is a class in the library that is getting modified. It was probably originally a class for convenience to the user.

def create_class(condition):
    if condition == 'A':
        parent_class = BaseA
    else:
        parent_class = BaseB
    
    class DynamicClass(parent_class):
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value

        def display(self):
            return f"{self.value} with {self.action()}"
    
    return DynamicClass


Unfortunately, this answer won't be useful for me because I need the user-facing API to stay the same, and this answer suggests to replace the class with a function.

Also, don't dynamically create the type, create the type outside the function, and choose from the existing types, otherwise, each instqance has it's own class

Make A a generic of either of the types.
For example, if you want to have a class with an attribute that is either a float or a Decimal:
from __future__ import annotations

from decimal import Decimal

from typing import Generic, TypeVar, cast, reveal_type


T = TypeVar("T", Decimal, float)


class A(Generic[T]):
    foo: T
    
    def __init__(self, foo: T) -> None:
        self.foo = foo

    def bar(self, x) -> None:
        # Other stuff...
        pass
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"<A: {self.foo} - {self.foo.__class__.__name__}>"


data_d = Decimal("1")
a_d = A(foo=data_d)
print(reveal_type(a_d))

data_f = 1.0
a_f = A(foo=data_f)
print(reveal_type(a_f))

Then MyPy outputs:
main.py:27: note: Revealed type is "__main__.A[_decimal.Decimal]"
main.py:31: note: Revealed type is "__main__.A[builtins.float]"

You should be able to apply the same technique to np.ndarray/cupy.ndarray.
